# How to use qtquick_compiler_add_resources in a CMake project that uses AUTORCC?

Tags: qt, cmake

I have a Qt Quick project that uses CMake as its build system. I mostly went with the Qt Creator-generated CMake project, so I have

```
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
```

in my root CMakeLists.txt.

I recently learned about ahead-of-time compiling for QML resources which is supposed to yield quite a bit of startup time improvement. The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/QtQuickCompiler/qquickcompiler-building-with-cmake.html) that describes how to use this with CMake says that I need to do the following:

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Quick Core Network)
find_package(Qt5QuickCompiler)
qtquick_compiler_add_resources(RESOURCES example.qrc)
add_executable(myapp ${SRC_LIST} ${RESOURCES})
qt5_use_modules(myapp Quick Core Network)
```

but as far as I see, `qtquick_compiler_add_resources` does nothing but produce a list of C++ files which don't exist. I assume those would be produced by the QtQuick compiler, but as it is, CMake doesn't run because it can't find those sources. What is the missing bit?

Comment: Not sure why that doesn't work, I just went through the same conversion of `AUTORCC` -> compiled and the above did work, i.e. `RESOURCES` is a list of cpp files generated by the quick compiler, which are than added to the executable (library in my case).

Comment: I mean the list itself looks fine. But nothing prompts the generation of those files.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, a bit late to the party but have to you tried removing the `set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)` ?

I have almost the same implementation and the `<qmlfile_name>_qml.cpp` files are generated and compiled correctly.

In my implementation I have :

- a different CMake property name (resource_files)
- I am not using AUTORCC
- I'm auto-generating the qrc/qmldir files in the build directory (but that shouldn't matter)
- I added the `qml files` list in the `add_executable` parameter list because I want to see them in my IDE.